# what is x/6 c b in GNU debugger dissembly

Tags: gdb

what is  stands for in GNU Debugger? It is  a just simple question from me as I don't understand?

```
 x/6 c b
```

Thanks First.

Comment: Have you tried writing `help x`?

Comment: i see, "showing 6 bytes in char"

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory